# Change password is not working

Tags: php

I have a problem with my change-password script. Can you please help me with this code? It should work, but it is not working. After clicking on the submit button, page just refreshes.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['ulozitzmeny']) && ($_SESSION['user']) && strlen($_SESSION['user']) > 0) {

    $password = hash('sha512', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['heslo']));
    $newpassword = hash('sha512', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['noveheslo']));
    $passwordconf = hash('sha512', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['potvrzenihesla']));

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='$_SESSION[user]'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if ($password != $row[0]) {

        echo" <div style='position:absolute;left:29.5%;top:10%;width:41%;' class='alert alert-danger fade in'>
             <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
             <strong>Chyba!</strong> NesprĂˇvnĂ© heslo!
             </div>";
    } else {

        if ($newpassword != $passwordconf) {

            echo" <div style='position:absolute;left:29.5%;top:10%;width:41%;' class='alert alert-danger fade in'>
             <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
             <strong>Chyba!</strong> Hesla se neshodujĂ­!
             </div>";
        } else {

            if (mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username = '$_SESSION[user]'")or die(mysql_query)) {

                echo" <div style='position:absolute;left:29.5%;top:10%;width:41%;' class='alert alert-success'>
             <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
             <strong>ĂšspÄ›ch!</strong> ZmÄ›ny probÄ›hly ĂşspÄ›ĹˇnÄ›!               
             </div>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us your form ?

Comment: Here is my form: http://pastebin.com/9FCsebpt

Comment: please try to print password value getting from $_POST and from database and try to check what you will get same value or not

Comment: @iWispy put in your question

Comment: Check if the posted attributes has values and make sure the session['user'] is set. Your code should works normally.

Comment: print your update query and check

Comment: Please have a look into [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php). Using the `hash` function is not recommended for storing passwords. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @iWispy if you're going to create a pastebin file, don't make it expire.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Notice: Undefined variable and Notice: Undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your form tag. From the one I saw at http://pastebin.com/9FCsebpt. I noticed that two necessary attributes are missing.

- Your form has no method attribute, so definitely will notpass through this condition `isset($_POST['ulozitzmeny'])`
- Your form has no action attribute. Hence, has not file to use for processing the script.

Correct these things in your form, and am sure your code will work.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now.

Comment: You are welcome.  Sometimes, those minor things escapes our mind

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in this request

```
"SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='$_SESSION[user]'"
```

If you use an array to get data you need to put `'` arround the key.

Try this request instead of :

```
"SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['user']."'"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's still not working...